# Twig replace filter - use part of regex match

Tags: templating

Using `replace` filter we can match pattern using regular expressions, but can we use part of the matched string in the second argument of filter? For example, I want to match all numbers and replace each matched number with a matched number enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft's `replace` filter will just use PHP's `preg_replace` method behind the scenes if it detects that a regular expression has been passed in.

It sounds like you're looking for the PHP [preg_match](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) method, which isn't available natively.

There was [a plugin](https://github.com/victor-sm/Craft-TwigPCRE) that added support for this in Craft 2, but I don't think it's been ported to Craft 3. You might be able to use that as a starting point if you'd like to port it, though.

Comment: I just created a Craft 3 version of this plugin with a few more filters. Still in testing before submission to plugin store but can be installed via composer command. https://github.com/indigoviking/expressive